# What is the V2002 in this XP means?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have a computer named: Windows XP, Professional, v2002, SP3 (this is from the Computer Details)

What is the V2002 meaning?

Was it the planned name for it?
Is it like the Windows 2003? Windows 2008?
Is it like the Build number?

we have a problem in one such computer, and I am not sure if this V2002 has anything to do with it.

Comment: `Version 2002` -- it's the year when Windows XP was released. I have the same on my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 2002 -- it's the year when Windows XP was released.